# React-native: How to chage View background color once click on a toggle switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to change the Background Color of the entire View by a toggle switch. But the color is not changing. Please help and Big Thanks!

Here is my code.

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Switch} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export default function App() {
const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);
const [color, setColor] = React.useState('yellow');

  return (
    <View style={[styles.container,
                 {backgroundColor:color}]}
          onValueChange = {color => setColor(color)}>

      <Switch onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
              value={isEnabled} onClick={() => setColor('grey')}>
      </Switch>

    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'column',
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define what happens when switch is enabled and what happens when switch is disabled. If enabled (conditional styling) background will be yellow, if not it'll be grey.

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Switch} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export default function App() {
const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);
const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);
const [color, setColor] = useState(true);

  return (    
    <View style={[styles.container, color  ? styles.bgyellow : styles.bggrey]}>
      <Switch onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
              value={isEnabled} onClick={() => setColor(!color)}>
      </Switch>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'column',
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  bgyellow:{
    background:'yellow'
  },
  bggrey:{
    background:'grey'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add conditional styling on the view where you want the color to be changed. Keep it simple and not confuse it. It would be something like this.

```
    const [isYellow, setIsYellow] = useState(false)

  return (
      <View style={isYellow ? {backgroundColor: 'yellow'} : {backgroundColor: 'grey'} }>
        <Switch onValueChange={() => setIsYellow(prevYellow => !prevYellow)}
              value={isEnabled}>
        </Switch>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the Bg-color to grey.

```js
const [color, setColor] = useState('yellow');
const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);


return(
  <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: color}]}>
    <Switch
      onValueChange={() => {
        setIsEnabled(!isEnabled);
        setColor('grey');
      }}
      value={isEnabled}></Switch>
  </View>
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you want to change the Bg-color to "grey" when Switch is disabled and "yellow" when the Switch is enabled

```js
const [color, setColor] = useState('grey');
const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);

const toggleSwitch = () => {
  setIsEnabled(!isEnabled);
  setColor(!isEnabled === true ? 'yellow' : 'grey');
};


return(
    <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: color}]}>
        <Switch onValueChange={toggleSwitch} value={isEnabled}></Switch>
    </View>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```